# Добавление/удаление/изменение exif у файла

Tags: c#, файлы, exif

**Доброго времени суток, ХешКодовцы!**

Очередная задачка повисла у меня. По интернету поискал и выяснил, что существует такая вещь как пользовательские атрибуты файла под название `Exif`. Все что смог найти, так это работа с `metadata exif` для картинок, но насколько я понимаю, данная информация может принадлежать не только картинкам, но и произвольному взятому файлу. Я прав?.. Данные свойства наблюдаются же у `doc`, `xls` документов. Значит теоретически, можно эти свойства повесить на любой файл.

У меня есть база данных. Хотелось бы ее описание запихнуть в `exif`, чтобы через свойства файла можно было бы узнать краткие сведения о ней, а не производить подключение и считывать некоторые данные из служебных таблиц. База данных формируется при помощи кода написанного на C#. Хотелось бы обойтись от посторонних готовых решений, а реализовать это все самостоятельно, если есть такая возможность. Если есть готовые решения в виде подключаемых модулей (`dll`), то ссылки на них пригодятся, в случае, если не получится реализовать функционал полностью самостоятельно.

**PS:** Решения в виде готовых продуктов не подходит, т.к. работа с файлами производится потоковое, по мере необходимости, и использование дополнительного продукта не приемлемо.

**Заранее спасибо за Вашу помощь!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я прав?

Нет.  Exif только для картинок/фотографий.

Обычно в каждом типе документов используется свой формат метаданных.

**Для изображений** это:

- Exif (англ. Exchangeable **Image** File Format) - чаще всего.
- XMP - используется программами Adobe

> XMP – гибкая платформа метаданных (Extensible Metadata Platform – XMP). Этот формат создан для добавления информации в файл. Формат XMP разработан так, что файл может прочитать любая программа, в том числе не умеющая работать с XMP. XMP используется в PDF, фотографии и редактировании изображений.

- IPTC

В файлах TIFF (Tagged Image File Format) есть теги, но они большей частью описывают технические параметры изображения, хотя есть поля для наименования и геометок

В `System.Drawing.Imaging` есть средства для манипуляции Exif данными. [Тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15621/EXIF-tag-Editor-for-JPG-images) пример программы для считывания и записи метаданных.

Для EXIF и XMP  есть готовая библиотека:  http://bitmaptagger.codeplex.com/

**Для музыкальных файлов** есть свои форматы метаданных. Среди них:

- ID3 разных версий
- APE
- Vorbis comments

Для манипуляции ними используется:

- [TagLib Sharp](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp)
- [IdSharp](http://www.idsharp.com/)

и другие

Метаданные (автор, заголовок, организация и т.д.) **в документах Office Open XML** (`*.docx`,  `*.xlsx`) извлекаются и редактируются с помощью [библиотек Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.document_properties.aspx)

**UPD.**

Если это всё происходит в пределах одного компьютера и на дисках используется NTFS, то можно попробовать сохранять эту служебную информацию в [альтернативных потоках данных](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), а потом сделать [утилиту](http://hex.pp.ua/nsx-05-alternate-data-streams.php) которая бы считывала и отображала то что вам надо. Или же проще - ложить ваш файл базы данных в архив, а вместе с ним какой-нибудь `META-INF` или `manifest.xml` или ещё что-то в этом роде, в котором будет эта служебная информация. И соответственно утилиту для её считывания и отображения.

Comment: Т.е. в моем случае для базы данных установить пользовательские атрибуты, которые я мог бы наблюдать в свойствах файла, не получится?..

Comment: А какие файлы? Они с сайта скачиваются, или на сайт загружаются, или формируются на лету? Какая конечная цель затеи?

Comment: Есть база данных формата firebird, формируется утилитой. В базе формируется служебная таблица с описанием базы, какие данные в ней будут храниться. Таких баз формируется много, для каждой задачи своя база. Сам файл шифруется под железный ключ. Необходимо знать служебную информацию (или ее часть). Не удобно догадываться по названию файла (иногда это и сделать не возможно). Не удобно тащить текстовый файл сопровождения с описание базы. Вот думал, что можно некоторую информацию поместить в пользовательские атрибуты...

Comment: Про ADS спасибо большое, покопаю в эту сторону, вполне возможно - это решение. Т.к. на всех рабочих местах давно уже используется NTFS, да Windows менее чем XP SP3 врят ли в организации встречу.