# Запись в свойства произвольного файла (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Добрый день! Интересуют именно **свойства**, а не атрибуты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел только как получить эти свойства:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx, а также то, что относится к определенным типам файлов:
[Добавление/удаление/изменение exif у файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/152705/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-exif-%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Мне же нужно **установить**, к примеру, описание файла, или, банально, его версию. Прошу помощи, как это сделать. Буду очень признателен за ответы!

Comment: Для произвольного файла нереализуемо. Для исполняемых фалов эта информация хранится в ресурсах, в VersionInfo. Скорее всего задача будет решаться парсингом ресурсов и изменением как вам нужно, но подводных камней там более чем.

Comment: А можете дать ссылку, куда глядеть и где можно о таком почитать? Файл у меня не исполняемый, потому хочется понимать, какие вообще инструменты есть для решения такого вида вопросов.

Comment: НЕТ решения для неисполняемых файлов. Просто нет, так как эта информация не предусмотрена форматом файлов. Для исполняемых даю ссылку на гугл: "исполняемый файл ресурсы" и "VersionInfo".

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов под неисполняемым подразумевался pe dll, насколько я понял

Comment: Коллеги, мне нужно для "txt" и для "dll"-файлов менять их версию. При чем созданы не мной.

Comment: @PashaPash DLL - исполняемый файл, хоть и не напрямую. Насколько я помню, даже в SYS может быть VersionInfo.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я про это знаю, но топикастер - нет

Comment: @vitaliklibra Нет для TXT решения: формата txt нет, соответственно нет в формате и информации о версии. Показанное на скриншоте - фича MZPE-файлов: EXE, DLL, SYS (грубо говоря).

Comment: Для dll - можно. Для txt - нет общепринятого способа задавать версию. Надо брать конкретный файл, у которого она задана, и смотреть как именно её прицепили

Comment: @PashaPash ошибаетесь по поводу моих знаний о исполняемых файлах)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не обязательно. Там ещё exif, и exif в alternate data stream. Метаданные можно почти к чему угодно прицепить - работал с этим пару лет назад. Но как именно - не вспомню. Надо лезть в исходники.

Comment: @PashaPash EXIF предусмотрен стандартом, хотя это и расширение формата JPG.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Вас понял. О MZPE-файлах не слышал. А вот для dll еще раз уточните: в c# нет способа программным образом поменять версию файла?

Comment: @vitaliklibra  в c# есть способ программно вызвать винапи. В винапи есть способ программно поменять версию dll.

Comment: @vitaliklibra Есть: IMAGE_DOS_HEADER -> IMAGE_NT_HEADERS -> IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE а дальше много, нудно и сложно. Если указанная в ответе API не подойдет в силу использования .NET

Comment: @vitaliklibra для других типов файла - зависит от зарегистирированных провайдеров свойств -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144129(v=vs.85).aspx . Для txt провайдера скорее всего нет, так что никак.

Comment: @ гм. http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/UpdateResource.html

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов подправил

Comment: Спасибо большое, что уделили время моему вопросу! Пока что пауза. Надо обработать новую информацию...

Comment: @PashaPash Хм, интересно как система будет копировать файлы с такой метаинформацией (в отдельных файлах) на съемные/сетевые носители.

Answer (score 4):

На чистом c# сделать не получится.

Если нужно поменять именно версию, и именно в exe или dll, то можно воспользоваться вызовом WinAPI [`UpdateResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049(v=vs.85).aspx) для перезаписи ресурса `VERSIONINFO/RT_VERSION`.

За основу можете взять готовую утилиту [verpatch](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/VerPatch.aspx?msg=3207401) или её исходники.

Если под рукой есть студия - то можно просто открыть ей dll, поправить ресурс и сохранить :)

Похожий вопрос на enSO: [How do I set the version information for an existing .exe, .dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/284258/1988244)